# autocomplete form field in php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

he every one i am trying to make autocomplete form from my sql here is code for index.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"
```

type="text/javascript">

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var ac_config = {
    source: "database_cities.php",
    select: function(event, ui){
        $("#area").val(ui.item.area);
        $("#city").val(ui.item.city);
        $("#state").val(ui.item.state);
        $("#zip").val(ui.item.zip);
        },
        minLength:1
        };
        $("#area").autocomplete(ac_config);
});

</script>
<form name="form" method="POST">
<p>
<label for="area">area</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="area" id="area" value=""  />
</p>

<p>
<label for="city">City</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="city" id="city" value=""/>
</p>
<p>
<label for="state">State</label>
<br />
<input type="text" name="state" id="state" value="" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="zip">Zip</label><br />
<input type="hidden" name="zip" id="zip" value="" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="store" />
</p>
</form>
```

and this is database_cities.php

```
<?php 
// Data could be pulled from a DB or other source
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could Not Connect"); 
mysql_select_db("dependency");  

$city_area=$_GET['area'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city LIKE '$city_area%'";
$data = mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data,MYSQL_ASSOC)){



$address = array(   
    array('city'=>$row['city'], state=>$row['state'], zip=>$row['postcode']), );
}

// Cleaning up the term
$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));  
// Rudimentary search
$matches = array(); foreach($address as $city){ if(stripos($city['city'], $term) !== false){
    // Add the necessary "value" and "label" fields and append to result set
    $city['value'] = $city['city']; 
    $city['label'] = "{$city['city']}, {$city['state']} {$city['zip']}";
    $matches[] = $city; } } 
    // Truncate, encode and return the results
    $matches = array_slice($matches, 0, 5);
    print json_encode($matches);
```

?>
i try to connect with mysql database it is connected and working but problem is that i just get the last row of my database i not get any other field can any one please tell me what i have to to to get all my data when i type in first field 
thanks

Comment: You are overwiting `$address` on each `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data,MYSQL_ASSOC))` loop. You need to make `$address` an array -> `$address[] = array( ..[your code].. );}`

Comment: Please, be careful with this code and use real_escape_string to prevent mysql injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the `$address` variable with every iteration, rather than appending as intended.

```
$address = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $address[] = array(
    'city' => $row['city'],
    'state' => $row['state'],
    'zip' => $row['postcode']
  );
}
```

The `[]` operator allows PHP to push a new value onto the end of the array, while automatically incrementing a numeric key.

Also, notice that I quoted the `state` and `zip` keys. You were likely getting PHP Notices about that.

Comment: i have got one more question with the same code. i want to search with zip code and city name. but with this code i can search just with city name, what i need to change in this code, thanks

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM cities WHERE city LIKE '$city_area%' AND postcode = '$zip'";`

Comment: and sir one more thing what changes in jquery codes because its not working i try to change but system gives code error what i have to do.  thanks for all of your efforts and help

Comment: i think there is no need to change in sql query($query = "SELECT * FROM cities") just this query is enough for this j query here is need to change in just in jquery. because i try to use only this query in my next try($query = "SELECT * FROM cities") and its works

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed you had programming experience. In addition to the SQL change I suggested, you will need to add the following line of code after the line `$city_area=…` : `$zip = $_GET['postal_code'];`, and you'll need to pass `postal_code` as a GET parameter. Also, don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.!